# NPM local server port increments by 1

Tags: npm, vue.js

new to VueJS here. Normally, vue runs the project at `localhost:8080`
I noticed lately that the moment I'm restarting my local server running at `localhost:8080` through `npm run dev` command, the default port just increased it's value by 1. (btw, i just had that screenshot few moments ago)

[image]

Is this some sort of an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the port 8080 and 8081 are already in use. You should make sure that you shutdown the running instances of the server before starting a new one.

Comment: I am only running this project and also, I am shutting it down since i figured out lately that vue sometimes, doesn't apply any of my changes in project

Comment: I'm not very familiar with vue.js but if i remember correctly, the port is set in the dev-block in the index.js file. If you could show your config for the project, that could be very helpful

Comment: `portfinder.basePort = process.env.PORT || config.dev.port
  portfinder.getPort((err, port) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else {
      // publish the new Port, necessary for e2e tests
      process.env.PORT = port
      // add port to devServer config
      devWebpackConfig.devServer.port = port`

this is a snippet I've found in webpack.conf.dev.js file

Comment: This looks like it tries to find a free port on it's own, so I assume some process is using port 8080 already. You could try to set the devServer.port to 8080 in this code but I don't know enough about that to be sure how to make it work, I can only guess.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I have found a solution regarding config file in webpack.